# Install icinga2 web as non root user / Source installation

Tags: installation, rhel, icinga

I am installing icinga2web, I need to copy files to `/usr/share` location to run icinga web. In order to do that we need `root` privilege.

Is there any other option available to install in some other location?
 I need to install `icinga` in remote host where I don't have `root` access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have downloaded all sources

```
httpd
php
postgresql
icinga2 core
icingaweb
```

compiled in my local setup, yes its works fine!! Now I can copy my binaries across my **VM**s everything works fine as any **USER**!!

Only one restriction is path hard coded!!!